# How are trades in kind recorded on property deeds?

Tags: united-states, real-estate

I think that when property is sold, the price is recorded on the deed, or in the registered record. However, what if property is sold in part or in full in kind? For example, what if somebody sells their property for cash plus a car, or they trade their property with somebody else, so it is a swap? How is the consideration recorded, if at all?

Comment: What country and why is the need to record consideration? Is this from taxes point of view or something else?

Comment: Typically such amounts should be recorded at the fair value of the goods being exchanged. For most purposes, that's how the IRS would view things, so it depends on what you mean by 'recording'.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon In the United States deeds are recorded by the county clerk. The deeds I have seen just have a short blank space to write in the amount of consideration.

Answer (score 1):

The usual recitation in a deed is "for one dollar and other valuable consideration, receipt of which is hereby acknowledged". Deeds are used to trace ownership of the property; the details of the payment don't affect ownership.